# Docusign - Upload brand profile through Rest API

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

I was going through the Docusign rest api - v2 and checking out the branding profile section. The documentation is pretty much self explanatory, thanks to Docusign. I am stuck with uploading the new banding profile service as its not clear what should be the content of zip file to be uploaded for adding new branding profile. Can someone please help me on this.

[Docusign RestAPI-V2](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to the DocuSign Console, go to Preferences -> Branding, then download one of your brand profiles (create one if you do not have any yet).  Once you download you'll see it's an xml file and it will show you the content of a brand profile.

Comment: Thanks Ergin for the response, I have few questions, Is XML the only way to upload new profile? What is the format of image file in XML?

Comment: There is some good documentation available at http://www.docusign.com/images/resources/documentation/Account_Branding.pdf. Any images associated with the brand are base64 encoded in the XML. The only format of the brand is XML.

Comment: Thanks Luis for the response